# Instagram API get most recent images around the world

Tags: instagram

I am using the Instagram API to fetch photos not tagged with a certain hashtag or from a certain location. I just like to fetch constantly the most recent uploaded images around the world.
How can I do that?

Comment: You want to use a timer, which call the fetch method repeatedly.

Answer (score -1):

use this api url

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

will be got response in json format.it would contains all most media like image, video. if you want images only from this response data  you can parser only image data  from this response data using field 'type:image'